# Is is recommended to start a new Asterisk system with version 12 or 11?

Tags: asterisk

I have to setup a new Asterisk system from the scratch.
I am very interested in the new REST interface of version 12 which is very much what I am using for other projects and like it's use because I have to setup the whole interface in the company too.
But because Version 12 is not an LTS version and I don't see so many using it I would like to know about your experience or what you recommend.
So would you recommend Starting with Version 12 or with Version 11 and what are your experiences when you know both systems?
Btw. The system is expected to go life in 6 months...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend use LTS version of asterisk for any new installs.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Versions

asterisk 12 is not LTS. so it not recommended unless you realy need new features(sophia-SIP or other)

Asterisk 12 have significant difference in sip due to stack change. For now some features(like accountcode) not developed yet. So it is not recommended for use if you have no extensive experience with asterisk/voip.

Also i not recommend use REST interface if you not understand asterisk internals like dialplan and channel work. Result will be unpredictable